# Transposing data from one dataframe to another..... Basic R Programming.

Tags: r, dataframe

I get the following style of table inside a for loop at every iteration.

```
> table
             Status                   Description
1                 Date:       Monday 19 November 1945
2                 Type: Curtiss R5C-1 Commando (C-46)
3             Operator:    United States Marine Corps
4         Registration:                         39592
5            C/n / msn:                            87
6         First flight:                          1944
7                 Crew:    Fatalities: 0 / Occupants:
8           Passengers:    Fatalities: 0 / Occupants:
9                Total:    Fatalities: 0 / Occupants:
10     Airplane damage:         Damaged beyond repair
11            Location:     Hishi-no-Shima (   Japan)
12               Phase:                 Unknown (UNK)
13              Nature:                      Military
14   Departure airport:                             ?
15 Destination airport:                             ?
16           Narrative:                 Force landed.
17      Probable Cause:                          <NA>
```

on every iteration, I wish to append this to the following dataframe:

```
>individual_status
[1] Date                 Time                 Type                 Operator             Registration        
[6] C_n_msn              First_flight         Crew                 Passengers           Total               
[11] Airplane_damage      Location             Phase                Nature               Departure_airport   
[16] Destination_airport  Narrative            Probable_Cause       Engines              Flightnumber        
[21] Total_airframe_hrs   Airplane_fate        Operating_for        Leased_from          Cycles              
[26] Crash_site_elevation Ground_casualties    Operated_by          On_behalf_of        
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

nrow(table$Status) keeps changing for every record and accordingly the description against it. All possible values of it are covered under colnames(individual_status)

Can someone please guide me on how to go about updating the individual_status data.frame for every iteration in a correct manner.

Comment: Please could you provide a link to a public file of your data in csv or tsv format so that we can import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
table$Status <- gsub(":", "", table$Status)

reshapedTable <- data.frame(lapply(table$Description, function(x) 
t(data.frame(x))))
names(reshapedTable) <- table$Status

require(plyr)
rbind.fill(reshapedTable, individual_status)
```

Comment: although not 100% but given my unclear requirements which were way too lame to put anywhere, I appreciate your efforts.
I got the solution after implementing your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here I created a minimal example of four columns:

```
status_codes1 <- c("Date", "Type", "Operator", "Registration")
status_codes2 <- paste(status_codes1, ":", sep = "") 

table1 <- data.frame(Status = status_codes2, Description = 1:4, stringsAsFactors = F)
table1

individual_status <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 0)), sample(status_codes1))

table2 <- table1[sample(1:4),]

append_to_is <- function()
{
    table2 <- table1[sample(1:4),]
    n_row <- nrow(individual_status)
    cols <- gsub(":", "", table2$Status)
    individual_status[n_row + 1, cols] <<- table2$Description
    return(list(table2, individual_status))
}
```

See that, the line with "table2":

```
table2 <- table1[sample(1:4),]
```

creates a copy of the original table1 with shuffled columns. In whatever order the new table is presented, first a regex replacement deletes the trailing colons ":", and then subsets the main df with the column names and appends to the next row.

The function returns the shuffled table and the appended individual status. You can restate the function as to your liking.